# Gradient-informed global optimization

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, extreme-value, gradient

I am looking for a review or comparison of [global optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) techniques where the gradient of the function is available and utilized to speed up search, like the following:

- [A hybrid descent method for global optimization](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AJOGO.0000015313.93974.b0?LI=true)
- [Gradient tabu search](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.20564/abstract)
- [An efficient algorithm for large scale global optimization of continuous functions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706005759)
- [Gradient-based cuckoo search for global optimization](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/493740/)
- [The q-gradient method for global optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2084)
- [Global optimization of Lipschitz functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02628)

I am performing optimization over hundreds of parameters, each fed into a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to yield a final value between 0 and 1. 
I have tried performing gradient descent using various techniques like [iRPROP+](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.17.1332), but keep getting stuck in local minima despite restarting the search at multiple points in the search space.

This makes me believe I need to use a global optimization technique that can escape from local minima. However, I would like to make use of the gradient of the function, which is available and can be used to speed up search.

Overfitting is not an issue in the problem I am tackling.

Comment: Sounds like this may be a use-case for Stochastic Gradient Hamiltonian Monte Carlo. https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4102

Comment: @Sycorax: I found the title of the paper you cited funny (from an Optimisation point of view) and just for laughs I searched  "Stochastic Quasi-Newton HMC." and apparently *it exists*! ["*Stochastic Quasi-Newton Langevin Monte Carlo*"](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/simsekli16.pdf). I am taking bets for when the "Box-constraints Stochastic Optimisation by Quadratic Approximations" will appear. :D (In all seriousness, these seem to be addressing important questions, I am just a bit surprised they are publication venues are not "classical" Optimisation publications.)